# WPF app( Maximum Column Width based on Character Count)

Tags: c#, wpf

I am writing a simple WPF application while facing trouble adjusting the width of column (Textbox) based on character count.

The simple program is email formatter, which deletes some special characters, the main function is fine, but this app should also enable users to select the length of each column for formatted output. The width is based on characters.

Is there any approach to solve this? The width ranges from 30 characters to 60, the default is 50

Much appreciated.

Comment: add Width="Auto" and height ="Auto"

Comment: @Isaac Guan : Can you post what you have tried and what problem you are facing ?

Answer (score 1):

Try setting the Height and Width to **Auto**. This might solve your problem. Something like this keeping in mind that there would be minimum 30 characters

```
 <TextBlock MinWidth="30" Height="Auto" Width="Auto" />
```

Comment: You can not set Min Max properties to Auto. Reason being ''NaN' is not a valid value for property 'MinWidth' , 'MaxWidth'

Comment: let him set the Width and Height property to Auto then ...and yeah I typed wrongly ! sorry I shall update my answer